# Magento2 Admin Menu - Add External URL

Tags: magento2

How to add an external link to admin menu? I have created controller and action to redirect but it is not working.

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add the script below to your js file:

```
$('li[data-ui-id="<DATA_UI_ID_OF_THE_MENU>"]').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = 'https://www.google.com';
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. add the link to your controller in the menu (file /etc/adminhtml/menu.xml)
2. create your custom admin controller (class in VENDOR/MODULE/Controller/Adminhtml/...) something like:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

   use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

   class Redirect extends Action
   {
        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->getImportUrl());
            return $resultRedirect; //<---- return is important
        }

        private function getImportUrl()
        {
           return 'https://www.google.com/';
        }
   }
   ```

Note: do not forget about return in controller